# Unmarshalling complex XML into java using Spring batch

Tags: xml, jaxb, xstream, spring-batch

I use Spring batch in order to parse XML documents and act upon the data contained in the those XML documents.

I have documents such as the one below:

```
<rootDoc>
  <group id="13001L000001" box="13000B000001" operator="jsmith">
    <mail numMail="3A06049714560"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714561"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714562"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714565"/>
  </group>
  <group id="13001L000002" box="13000B000001" operator="jsmith">
    <mail numMail="3A06049714570"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714571"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714572"/>
    <mail numMail="3A06049714575"/>
  </group>
</rootDoc>
```

Ideally, for each document I want to be able to obtain a collection of `group`s and for each group a collection of `mail`s

I am not sure how to use XStream for that purpose... Is it possible to achieve what I want to do with XStream or do I need JaxB?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Batch but the JAXB mappings for that XML document would be pretty straight forward.  The following article should help you get going:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XStream would be the 'easiest' imho - essentially allowing you to quickly construct a set of POJO's that would map the document and then use XStream configurations to parse the document into them.  for instance for the rootDoc;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Root implements Serializable {

private List<Group> groups;

//setters and getters...

}
```

for the Group

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Group implements Serializable {

private String id;

private String box;

private String operator;

private List<Mail> mailItems;

//setters and getters...

}
```

and for the Mail Item

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Mail implements Serializable {

private String numMail;

//setters and getters...

}
```

to setup XStream for this object the following configuration could be used

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("mail", Mail.class);
    xstream.useAttributeFor(Mail.class,"numMail");
    xstream.alias("group", Group.class);
    xstream.useAttributeFor(Group.class, "box");
    xstream.useAttributeFor(Group.class, "id");
    xstream.useAttributeFor(Group.class, "operator");
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Group.class, "mailItems");
    xstream.alias("rootDoc", Root.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Root.class, "groups");
```

and to use it to read the document

```
Root result = (Root) xstream.fromXML(...source);
```

now you can use the Root POJO as you would any parent object and retrieve the corresponding Groups and Mail Items.

Answer (score 0):

XStream is mainly used for marshalling and unmarshalling of xml, what you can to is to unmarshall the xml into java objects, and then run through these objects and do your task.

If you want to "react" to data as it comes I would rather advise using a sax/stax reader that reacts to different tags.

Since JaxB is mentioned, it does allmost the same as XStream. From experience I allmost exclusivly find XStream easier to work with. However, if you want to know more in detail about the differences look at this post: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4230499/java-to-xml-conversions This post also talks about several other solution that may be relevant for you.

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) is designed to start from Java classes.  You do not need to generate them from an XML schema:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: Thank you, I've obiously missed that point. I edited my answer, so I am not to misinform other people.